# Let $X_M^c$ be the space of vector fields on a manifold $M$ with compact support. Prove that $X_M^c=[X_M^c,X_M^c]$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $X_M^c$ be the space of vector fields on a manifold $M$ with compact support. Prove that $X_M^c=[X_M^c,X_M^c]$.

Proving that $[X_M^c,X_M^c]\subset X_M^c$ is relatively simple. However, I have not been able to prove $X_M^c\subset [X_M^c,X_M^c]$. Any clues?

Comment: Is the problem easier/well known when $M$ is compact and you consider all vector fields?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier- Yes, I was thinking that in that case $X=[1,X]$. But $1$ is not a vector field....so maybe there's a clever vector field that essentially serves as a unit for this lie bracket operation....

Comment: Have you worked it out explicitly for $M=\Bbb R$?